# PHP: Possible to automatically get all POSTed data And Multiple checkbox unchecked?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

Hello friends i have a trouble.

I'm trying to use this code to get dynamically, variables and values of a form, but there is a countless number checkbox, which may or not marked, I would like to know how can I get an off or "0" in case not this a checkbox labeled, these data have been used .ajax and data:

Short Example of checkboxes:

```
<input name="p-sis-0110-1" type="checkbox">
<input name="p-sis-0110-2" type="checkbox">
<input name="p-sis-0110-3" type="checkbox">
<input name="p-sis-0110-4" type="checkbox">
<input name="p-sis-0110-5" type="checkbox">
<input name="p-sis-0110-6" type="checkbox">
```

or

```
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="input[]" type="checkbox">
```

Ajax:

```
.$("#formarea").serialize()
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>"
}
```

I appreciate any help to solve this little dilemma.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes aren't posted at all. You can keep a list of them in a hidden field, if you want, but they otherwise will not be communicated to the server at all.

Comment: Did you give up on this or what???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only "*successful*" controls are submitted.  An unchecked checkbox or radio button is not "*successful*".

You need to declare a default value with a hidden input.  Make sure the hidden input comes before the checkbox so if the checkbox is checked it will override the default hidden input since the names are the same:

```
<input name="p-sis-0110-1" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="p-sis-0110-1" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

To use an array you need to explicitly define the indexes so they are the same:

```
<input name="input[0]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="input[0]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: the hidden field would be overwritten in the post sent?

Comment: Yes, if the checkbox is check then it will override the hidden since the names are the same.